# XCode plist display as HTML with formatting such as bold

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, plist

I am trying to get a plist to display in a list, which works but I need formatting to it but everything I try to do doesn't work out.

Here is my code:

```
eNSAttributedString *attributedString = 
   [[NSAttributedString alloc]
   initWithData: [self.detailTextContents
   dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
   options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } 
   documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

NSString *str = [attributedString string];

self.detailText.text = str;
```

Hope you guys can help me out.
Thanks